# Mysql - get the number of entries with a timestamp in the last week as a % of the total entires

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a timestamp col and around 100000 rows, how can I find the % of the total entries that have a timestamp in the last week? I can find the number of entries

```
SELECT count(*) c FROM table t WHERE timestamp_col > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

but how would I then work that back to a % of the total rows?

I can do this imperatively with 2 statements but am wondering if there is an SQL only solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do this easily.  Here is a short way:

```
SELECT avg(timestamp_col > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) )
FROM table t;
```

MySQL treats boolean values as integers with `1` being true and `0` being false.

The above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT sum(timestamp_col > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ) / count(*)
FROM table t;
```

Comment: This felt like magic for several minutes while I figured out how that works! I just learned something really useful - Brilliant, thank you!